# PHP: Return all 24 hours format hours between two days as string

Tags: php

How can I print all hours between two dates in PHP?
Expected:
01:00 AM
02:00 AM
.
.
21:00 PM

Comment: Hi ramin, could you please add what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [suresh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51701521/3552932) answer is correct in most cases it doesn't cover all of them.

When timezones, daylight saving time comes into play things get messy.

Consider using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
$from = new DateTime("2018-01-10 10:00:00 UTC");
$to = new DateTime("2018-01-10 16:00:00 UTC");
$interval = new DateInterval("PT1H");

for ($now = clone $from; $now < $to; $now->add($interval)) {
    echo $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e  -->  H:i A") . "\n";
}
```

Will output nicely

> ```
> 2018-01-10 10:00:00 UTC  -->  10:00 AM
> 2018-01-10 11:00:00 UTC  -->  11:00 AM
> 2018-01-10 12:00:00 UTC  -->  12:00 PM
> 2018-01-10 13:00:00 UTC  -->  13:00 PM
> 2018-01-10 14:00:00 UTC  -->  14:00 PM
> 2018-01-10 15:00:00 UTC  -->  15:00 PM
> ```

But this code will also cover time changes

```
$from = new DateTime("2018-03-24 20:00:00 Europe/Warsaw");
$to = new DateTime("2018-03-25 06:00:00 Europe/Warsaw");
$interval = new DateInterval("PT1H");

for ($now = clone $from; $now < $to; $now->add($interval)) {
    echo $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e  -->  H:i A") . "\n";
}
```

> ```
> 2018-03-24 20:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  20:00 PM
> 2018-03-24 21:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  21:00 PM
> 2018-03-24 22:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  22:00 PM
> 2018-03-24 23:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  23:00 PM
> 2018-03-25 00:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  00:00 AM
> 2018-03-25 01:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  01:00 AM
> 2018-03-25 03:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  03:00 AM
> 2018-03-25 04:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  04:00 AM
> 2018-03-25 05:00:00 Europe/Warsaw  -->  05:00 AM
> ```

Note there is no 02:00 AM, since we switched to summer time (CET to CEST timezone)

Answer (score 0):

Try  with for loop  it will print  the hours between two values

```
$a = '05:00';
$b = '10:00';

// convert the strings to unix timestamps
$a = strtotime($a);
$b = strtotime($b);

// loop over every hour (3600sec) between the two timestamps
for($i = 0; $i < $b - $a; $i += 3600) {
  // add the current iteration and echo it
  echo date('H:i', $a + $i).'<br>';
}

?>
```

Output:

```
    05:00
    06:00
    07:00
    08:00
    09:00
    10:00
```